# How can you connect two outside processes from within a perl script?

Tags: perl, sockets, vim, xdebug

What I'm trying to do is get the Xdebug debugger running on a file in a vim session, all from a perl script. If I wanted to do this from the command line, I would open vim, then issue a command (specific to the debugger) in vim that makes vim listen to port 9000 (by pressing F5 in normal mode), and then open the page I want to debug in a browser, which starts the debugging session in vim. I have done this with success.

For doing it within perl, my idea has been to use a fork and system calls.

```
use LWP::Simple;

if ($pid = fork) {
    system('vi -c ":normal ^[[15~"');
} else {
    sleep;
    get 'http://localhost/homepage/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1';
    exit(0);
}
```

(The '-c ":normal ^[[15~"' option makes vim start out by waiting for a new connection on port 9000.)

This doesn't work. The problem seems to have to do with sockets, as far as I can tell. Is there a way to get too processes to talk to one another across such a connection from within perl?

Answer (score 0):

Making the connection from within vim works:

```
vim -c 'let x = system("sleep 2; wget http://localhost/homepage/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1; &")' -c 'normal ^[[15~'
```